# How to get alert,confirmation boxes using angular 2

Tags: angular, alert, popupwindow, angular2-modal

I have a requirement to implement alert box in my project on click of a button depending on various conditions. Can you please suggest me how to implement alert box using Angular 2 and I don't require traditional window.alert()

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap

Comment: can we make it without using bootstrap

Comment: Is there no way to get a $window.alert?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of angular2 package

npm install ng2-modal --save

```
`<button (click)="myModal.open()">Show popup</button>
    <modal #myModal>
        <modal-header>
            <h1>Your header goes here</h1>
        </modal-header>
        <modal-content>
            Body goes here
        </modal-content>
        <modal-footer>
            <button class="btn btn-primary (click)="myModal.close()">Cancel</button>
        </modal-footer>
    </modal>`
```

For more details : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-modal